# python daemon not calling other python script

Tags: python, python-daemon, start-stop-daemon

I am using python daemon to check a particular table in mongodb if there is any value it should call another python script.
Below is the code what I am trying, but it doesn't call the script.
can somebody help me out:

```
import daemon
import time
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient


connection = MongoClient(IPADDRESS, PORT)
monitor_db = connection.testmongo.XYZ_monitoring

def interval_monitoring():
    while True:
        searchForm = monitor_db.find()
        for user in searchForm:
            user_id=user['user_id']
            for ids in user_id:
                path= "python XYZ.py "+ids
                os.system(path)
        time.sleep(60)


def run():
    print daemon.__file__
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        interval_monitoring()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 1):

yes i got it. Am posting as it may be it helps someone

Instead of using

```
os.system(path)
```

Use:

```
subprocess.call(['python', '/Path_from_root_directory/XYZ.py', ids]) // ids is my argument to be passed
```